# How can i populate a DropdownList Options in React without states?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I dont want to use states because this is my 2nd dropdown and its connected to the first one. And i found out when i do `this.setstate(...);` react is re-render and its breaks my first dropdownlist every selected forms are unselecting. So i want to use this:

```
const data =[{
   "tablename": "demo_1",
   "segments": "asd"
},
{
   "tablename": "demo_2",
   "segments": "dsa"
}];
```

And i want something simple like this:
[image]

Is it possible to do that ? I searched but cant find a decent answer.

Comment: you can try using ref, like https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html, but truly its a bad option, and always better to handle it using state like you can move these two dependent dropdown as a seperate component and handling the setstate inside that, which inturn wont affect your form,

Comment: You might be setting the state wrong, or there could be another problem when you set the state. Could you please post the code that you use to populate both dropdownlists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like your component state doesn’t live high enough in your component hierarchy. Try storing state in a parent component, and passing it down to your drop downs as props.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommend,but if you have to keep the two dropdown,you may try shouldComponentUpdate to prevent the re-render.Here is an example.

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state... == nextState...) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```